# Solutions of triangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

$AA_1$, $BB_1$, $CC_1$ are the medians of triangle $ABC$ whose centroid is $G$. If points $A, C_1, G, B_1$ are concylic then prove that $2a^2= b^2 + c^2$.

Thanks

My try:-
$ar(GBC)=1/3ar(ABC)$

$\frac{1}{2}(GB.GC.\sin(\pi-A))=\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2}bc\sin A)$

$GB.GC=\frac{1}{3}bc$

Now I can't think any further. Here is my diagram:

[image: My diagram]

Comment: Hi and welcome to M.S.E what have you tried on the problem

Comment: i couldn't think of anything, what I have done is in the post now...I know that wouldn't be correct.

Comment: please help me solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the line $B_1C_1$, which is parallel to $BC$. Hence we have $\angle GC_1B_1=\angle GCB$. But $AB_1C_1G$ lie on a circle. Therefore we have:
$$
\angle GC_1B_1=\angle GAB_1\implies \angle GCB=\angle GAB_1.
$$
Therefore the triangles $GA_1C$ and $AA_1C$ are similar and hence we have:
$$
\frac{A_1C}{GA_1}=\frac{AA_1}{A_1C}.
$$
 Call the length of $AA_1$, $m_a$. We know that $GA_1=\frac{m_a}{3}$. Therefore we get:
$$
a^2=\frac{4}{3}m_a^2
$$
Now it is enough to replace $m_a^2$ by its length in terms of $a,b,c$:
$$
m_a=\sqrt{\frac{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}{4}}
$$
and the result follows.

Comment: thanks Arash for the answer:)

Answer (score 2):

It is really very simple. Using power of point property

$$BC_{1}.BA=BG.BB_{1}$$

$$\frac{c}{2}.c=\frac{2}{3}m_{b}.m_{b}$$

$$3c^2=4m^2_{b}$$

$$3c^2=2a^2+2c^2-b^2$$

$$2a^2=b^2+c^2$$